# How can I deliberately slow Windows?

Tags: windows, performance

How do I reversably slow a PC with XP?

I want to achieve this without using visible CPU-cycles, so I'm guessing some hardware settings might do.

I don't want my app to run slow, I want the whole OS to be slow. I know some network lookups especially out of a trusted environment (think Active Directory) slow a PC way down. This is the effect I want.

Disclaimer: this is not for a bad/evil/illegal cause!

Comment: How do you deliberately slow Windows?

<smartarse>Use it!</smartarse>

Comment: Actually, Windows does the work of slowing itself for you! It's *that* user friendly. =)

Comment: Actually, he said "reversably" so he's asking for a non-standard method! ☺

Comment: I can only imagine this being used for evil...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We use a 'crippled' server we call doofus for load testing. it is an old P3/500 box with limited RAM.

Another option is setting up a VM with very limited resources.

Comment: I agree with the crippled VM.  That is going to probably be simpler than trying to intentionally crippling the OS itself.

Comment: +1 for the VM suggestion. But poor crippled server... I'll call server protection services! ;)

Comment: I'm giving +1 simply for the name being "doofus"

Comment: I like this idea a lot.  Old hardware is free.  Sometimes people will even pay you to take it away because they don't want to have to pay the (much higher) disposal fees.  You could have a nearly infinite number of 8 year old test machines...

Comment: Thanks, the VM way proved to be the answer in the end.

Answer (score 6):

Use [powercfg.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940.aspx), to force the computer to a power plan you've created that locks the CPU into a lower frequency to conserve power.  What states are available depend on your platform (most desktops only have a couple.)

Comment: Had a look, but it's not good enough, as its just a cmd line interface to the standard windows power settings. Thanks though.

Comment: On windows 10 lenovo laptop (T460), I did "max battery life" in power options and it completely crippled the laptop.

Answer (score 5):

If you think your hardware setup can handle it, some motherboards let you manually specify a clockspeed multiplier or other speed settings in the BIOS. Often there'll be an option for a slower speed or a field where you can manually enter a lower multiplier.

If not, you might consider setting up a virtual machine, and making sure it's not fully virtualized - paravirtualized machines run slower due to the necessary translations that take place in the virtualization layer.

Answer (score 3):

The open source [Bochs emulator](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) is pretty easy to slow down by editing its config file. Windows XP will run in it. It is not as powerful as vmware, but there are many  more configuration options.

Look at the documentation for the config file, "bochsrc", and particularly the "IPS" entry. (Instructions Per Second)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the thermopaste and put some dust on the CPU :-) Also, remove some RAM.

Comment: there's a simpler way to do it - you can set the /MAXMEM switch in XP. See my post.

Comment: @amdfan - I know of /maxmem, but he said he wanted a hardware solution.

Comment: Actually maxmem could work, I just didn't want to bog down the cpu with an app I wrrote to simulate slowness.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at a full-system simulator such as [Simics](http://www.virtutech.com/). Simics allows you deterministically simulate an entire system (including networks, if you want). Not only can you tweak the CPU frequency, you can study the system in detail to see how it behaves.

Unfortunately, Simics has quite a pricetag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see really dramatic effects very easily, set the [/MAXMEM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/108393) switch in boot.ini (or use msconfig). This will limit the amount of memory used by the system - switching to 256mb or lower would make things very, very slow.

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of options. Things I can think of:

1. Change your disks to good old fashioned IDE. None of that high-speed DMA stuff, just good old fashioned PIO.
2. Remove RAM (or diable in the BIOS)
3. Switch to generic video drivers (I mean "Generic SVGA" type, that are un-accelerated)
4. Disable core(s) in the BIOS
5. Slow the CPU down in the bios (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

We keep an old laptop around for this reason. Helped me to find a subtle timing issue in some splash screen code that was absolutely unreproducable on decent quad core dev boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Install Norton 360. It makes the mouse cursor lag during updates and constantly nags for restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the L2 cache in the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Two Windows applications: [Mo'Slo](http://moslo.info/) and [Cpukiller](http://www.cpukiller.com/).

I remember hearing of one that grabs large chunks of RAM, to reduce your available RAM, but I forget what it is called.